# What am I doing incorrect in this directory search python code?

Tags: python, directory, directory-structure

What am I doing wrong in the following source code and how can I fix that?

**my_script.py**

```
import subprocess
import os
import time
from pathlib import Path

def get_files(dir_str):
    onlyfiles = next(os.walk(dir_str))[2] 
    return onlyfiles


input_files_path_str = "$HOME"


def main():
    input_files_list = get_files(input_files_path_str)
    print(input_files_list)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
user_name@server_name:~$ python3 my_script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_script.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "my_script.py", line 15, in main
    input_files_list = get_files(input_files_path_str)
  File "my_script.py", line 7, in get_files
    onlyfiles = next(os.walk(dir_str))[2]
StopIteration
user_name@server_name:~$
```

Comment: An [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) should say what the expected behaviour is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.walk` does not expand the shell variables(In this case it's `$HOME`) automatically.
You need to use [`os.path.expandvars` api](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars) to expand it before supplying to `get_files`.

```
import os.path
input_files_list = get_files(os.path.expandvars(input_files_path_str))
```